# Binding draggable points together

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, perspective

I'm using a script called [PerspectiveTransform.js](https://github.com/edankwan/PerspectiveTransform.js) to transform the perspective of an image by dragging the corners.

This script works as expected. However, I'm trying to transform the perspective of two separate images.

I've got this to work for two separate images. What I'm trying to achieve however, is that the two right points of the **left image** are binded with their corresponding points of the **right image**.

So when I drag the top right point of the **left image**, the top left point of the **right image** should also move.

[image]

I tried declaring different values for the variable `pts`, but this just ended up in me moving all the points at the same time.

Any suggestions on how to handle this are more than welcome.

**[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maohvupv/4/)**

I've managed to read out the correct points with an if statement in the mousedown function.

```
pts.mousedown(function(e) {       

        if( $(this).parent('#containerv2').length &&  $(this).is('.bl') ||     $(this).parent('#containerv2').length && $(this).is('.tl') ){
            //Action
        }
...
```

So next I tried to make another target when I've recognized that the bottom left corner for the right image is activated. When this happens I create another target and execute a duplicate function of onMousemove.

This however fails to works, and I fail to see why.

```
 function onMouseMove(e) {
        targetPoint.x = e.pageX - container.offset().left;
        targetPoint.y = e.pageY - container.offset().top;
        target.css({
            left : targetPoint.x,
            top : targetPoint.y
        });

        // check the polygon error, if it's 0, which means there is no error
        if(transform.checkError()==0){
            transform.update();
            img.show();
        }else{
            img.hide();
        }
    }

    function onMouseMove2(e) {
        targetPoint2.x = e.pageX - container.offset().left;
        targetPoint2.y = e.pageY - container.offset().top;
        targetExtra.css({
            left : targetPoint2.x,
            top : targetPoint2.y
        });

        // check the polygon error, if it's 0, which means there is no error
        if(transform.checkError()==0){
            transform.update();
            img.show();
        }else{
            img.hide();
        }
    }

    pts.mousedown(function(e) { 

        if( $(this).parent('#containerv2').length &&  $(this).is('.bl') ){
            //Action
            targetExtra = $('#containerv1 .br');
            targetPoint2 = targetExtra.hasClass("tl") ? transform.topLeft : targetExtra.hasClass("tr") ? transform.topRight : targetExtra.hasClass("bl") ? transform.bottomLeft : transform.bottomRight;
            onMouseMove2.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
            $(window).mousemove(onMouseMove2);
            $(window).mouseup(function() {
                $(window).unbind('mousemove', onMouseMove2);
            })
        }

        target = $(this);
            targetPoint = target.hasClass("tl") ? transform.topLeft : target.hasClass("tr") ? transform.topRight : target.hasClass("bl") ? transform.bottomLeft : transform.bottomRight;
            onMouseMove.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
            $(window).mousemove(onMouseMove);
            $(window).mouseup(function() {
                $(window).unbind('mousemove', onMouseMove);
            })
    });
```

**[Updated Fiddle that fails](http://jsfiddle.net/maohvupv/5/)**

Comment: a solution to your problem could be passing the mousedown event twice while setting `e.target.style.pointerEvents = 'none';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using custom attributes to "pair" points together, firing mousedown events for one when the paired point's mousedown event fires.

Here is a quick fiddle that illustrates this concept: http://jsfiddle.net/spesk8q7/

As you can see, I pair the points together with the `data-pointpair` attribute before you run the `perspecDrag` function:

```
$("#containerv2 .pt.tl").attr("data-pointpair", "#containerv1 .pt.tr");
$("#containerv2 .pt.bl").attr("data-pointpair", "#containerv1 .pt.br");
```

I then fire the paired point's mousedown event within the `mousedown` event handler:

```
if($(this).attr("data-pointpair"))
{
    $($(this).attr("data-pointpair")).mousedown();                
}
```

Be careful with this though.  If you decide to set the `data-pointpair` attribute on the already-paired points, there is a potential infinite loop scenario without further safety checks.

Comment: "Be careful with this though. If you decide to set the data-pointpair attribute on the already-paired points, there is a potential infinite loop scenario without further safety checks."

Could that scenario be triggered by anything other than setting it manualy?

Comment: That is a scenario that would happen if you set two points' `data-pointpair` attribute to each other manually.  If you don't do that, you are safe.